# My Scrollview doesn't scroll all the way up after pushing up the keyboard Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have a scrollview with lots of textfields inside it. When I push up my scroll view so that the keyboard does not hide some of the subviews, I can't scroll all the way up to the top of scrollview. Here is my code. Can anyone help?

[image: constraints of uiscrollview]

```
class IncomingPackageViewController: UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector:#selector(self.keyboardWillShow),name:UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide),name:UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)

    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
            let frame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {return}
        let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: frame.height, right: 0)
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= contentInset.bottom
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really be using [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html) instead of static frames

Comment: You could also try using the `keyboardDidShow` notification as this notification is for after the keyboard has appeared.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the  `scrollView.contentInset`, you shouldn't mess with the ViewControllers view frame.

I also recommend that you use a `tableView` since it gives you that behavior for free.